# image popup window based on text from a form

Tags: javascript, html

Just want to let you all know in advance that I am new to html/javascript coding, so I apologize if this question seems too simple.  I've tried to research the answer and can't seem to find exactly want I want to do.

What I want to do is have a very simple form that will popup an image based on what is entered in the form. ie. if you enter an "a" it will popup a picture of an apple, but if you enter a "b", it will popup a picture of a bird.

I found 2 pieces of code, one for the simple form and one for the popup (however, the popup was based on clicking a link and not a form entry)

I can't figure out how to combine the two.  Here's what I have...

http://sparkycat4e.com/htmlformtest3.html

Sorry, I had to post a link, when I copied my code, it tried to run it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your source code and you almost got it if not for some stray brackets and typos. I cleaned it up a bit here (just put all js code in one `<script>` tag) and made some small improvements (use `switch`, and use camelCase for names):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var newWindow = '';

function popItUp(url) {
  if (newWindow.location && !newWindow.closed) {
    newWindow.location.href = url;
    newWindow.focus();
  } else {
    newWindow = window.open(url, 'htmlname', 'width=404,height=316,resizable=1');
  }
}

function allLetter(text) {
  switch (text) {
    case "a":
      popItUp("https://www.apple.com/ac/structured-data/images/knowledge_graph_logo.png?201709101434");
      break;
    case "b":
      popItUp("https://i.pinimg.com/736x/03/59/20/035920dbccef6d85fee537765a5c3f08--celebrity-videos-celebrity-baby-names.jpg");
      break;
    default:
      alert('Please input alphabet characters only');
  }
}
</script>
```

Your form now passes the value directly on submission:

```
<form name="form1" action="#">
  <ul>
    <li>Code:</li>
    <li><input type='text' name='text1' /></li>
    <li class="rq">*Enter alphabets only.</li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="allLetter(document.form1.text1.value)" /></li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed.  Thank you so much.  Just 1 more question please.  How do you paste the code into the post as a text block and not have it interpret it as code.  That way I don't have to put the website page in there and have someone download the source code.   Hope this makes sense  Thanks again

Comment: Well just paste it there and format it as code sample ({} from the menu). Try it. Should be easy.

Comment: Got it.  Once again, that was exactly what I needed.  Thanks again.